# How to add checkboxes in dropdownlist using bootstrap in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to use checkbox inside dropdownlist using bootstrap but did not get it to work

It is working without visual studio, when I open the html file directly but not working in visual studio

By the way I am using visual studio 2017 community version

Here is the working screenshot of my code

[image]

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
            $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
                var selected = $("#lstFruits option:selected");
                var message = "";
                selected.each(function () {
                    message += $(this).text() + " " + $(this).val() + "\n";
                });
                alert(message);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
    <select id="lstFruits" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Mango</option>
        <option value="2">Apple</option>
        <option value="3">Banana</option>
        <option value="4">Guava</option>
        <option value="5">Orange</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="btnSelected" value="Get Selected" />
```